# Play! Framework 2.0 CoffeeScript/Less workflow in 1.2.x

Tags: playframework, coffeescript, less, playframework-2.0

The upcoming version 2.0 of the Play! Framework offers a great workflow for CoffeeScript and Less code in that respective files are kept in a separate asset folder and compiled to the actual JS/CSS files following the build process one is used to in Play.

My question is whether any means of achieving this kind of behavior in 1.2.x versions exists. If not, how would one go about getting it to work in a "play'y" way? The latter question probably translates to "How do I hook into the Play build process?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are modules for both LESS and CoffeeScript in Play 1.x. See

http://www.playframework.org/modules/less

and

http://www.playframework.org/modules/coffee

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Wondering why I didn't come across these before by myself.

Comment: the modules page is getting a little difficult to navigate now the number of modules has got so large.